# If condition passes, but the code is not executed

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, vbscript

I'm facing a problem with my GUI test. I want to check if a certain screen of an application is loaded or not; for this I'm using a bitmap checkpoint and a test area checkpoint. I'm using both because sometimes the bitmap checkpoint is so sensitive and fails for a little change in the image, so to I decided to use a test area for this.

My problem is that I'm using a infinite loop with a counter timer. If the time becomes greater than X seconds, exit the loop and report. If not, check the checkpoints: if one passes, exit the loop and report. When I run this script, the code does not exit the infinite loop, even though the Results View indicates that the second checkpoint passed! Why didn't it exit the loop?

Also, I used the same code in another action and it works! The only difference is that the other action I'm using has more checkpoints. So I am really not understanding what is happening.

The functions `write_log` and `Report_results` are just a way to keep the results. I don't think they are the problem because I checked them individually and they seemed to work fine.

```
Function Report_results(x1,y1,Value,x2,y2,sheet)

    Set myxl = createobject("excel.application")
    myxl.Workbooks.Open "R:\data\hpc_uat\CAEDev\nbak\czp2hk\bench_log_results_v3.xlsx"
    myxl.Application.Visible = false
    Set mysheet_logs = myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet)
    mysheet_logs.cells(x1,y1).value = Value
    mysheet_logs.cells(x2,y2).value = Now 
    myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    myxl.Application.Quit

    Set mysheet_logs = nothing
    Set myxl = nothing

End Function

Function write_log(path, value)

    Set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set logFile = fso.GetFile(path)

    Set objWTS = logFile.OpenAsTextStream(8,0)

    objWTS.WriteLine (value)
    objWTS.WriteLine ("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    objWTS.WriteBlankLines(1)
    objWTS.Close

    Set fso = nothing
    Set objWTS = nothing

End Function

'MAIN CODE

available = true

startTime = timer

Do
    If startTime>400000 Then
        Report_results aux, 3, (startTime)/100000, aux, 12, "bench_logs"        
        write_log path, "chk_point_1 not passed, time exceed 40s"
        ExitTest 
    Else
        If (Window("Gompute Desktop:.*").WinObject("gomputeWindow").Check (CheckPoint("chk_point_1_primer_GMB_v1")) = true) Then    
            write_log path, "chk_point_1_v1 passed"
            Exit Do
            End If
        If (Window("Gompute Desktop:.*").WinObject("gomputeWindow").Check (CheckPoint("chk_point_1_primer_GMB_v2")) = true) Then    
            write_log path, "chk_point_1_v2 passed"
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop While available = true

stopTime = timer

totalTime = stopTime-startTime

write_log path, "chk_point_1 passed"
Report_results aux, 2, totalTime, aux, 12, "bench_logs"
```

Here is just a sample of the Results Viewer that shows a checkpoint passed, but the code keeps checking the checkpoints, indicating that the code didn't break out of the infinite loop.

[image]

Comment: So, the `Check`and `Checkpoint` is a method of UFT, I only capture the image what I want to check, and UFT make the comparison for me. I can set some tolerances to make sure that it will not fail for a small difference between the images. And the `write_log` is only to report what checkpoint is passed, but the problem is that the checkpoint pass, but the `write_log`and the `Exist Do` is not executed.

Comment: I think you mean that the `Check` and `CheckPoint` are executed but do not pass. If they passed then I would expect the `write_log path, "chk_point_1_v... passed"` to write something and that is why I asked for the output of the `write_log` lines.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I expected this too, but for some reason the code not stop to check the checkpoints, even they exceed the timer.

Comment: A couple stabs in the dark from looking at http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Und_Chkpt_Statements.htm -- they seem to hide a lot of their documentation and I don't use uft, but: 1) is it correct to be comparing a checkpoint to a boolean? their example shows just passing a `Checkpoint` to the `Check`. Also, from their example it looks like `Check` is a procedure, not a function, so try removing the parentheses around the Checkpoint and boolean comparison. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/

Comment: This just smells like somehow the `Checkpoint` call is what's being shown as passing or failing in the Results Viewer, but the actual `Check` call is returning false.

Comment: Oh you're right! Don't need to put `= true` inside the `if`, only put a parentheses between the `Checkpoint`. Now it's working. Thanks for the help guys, the thread can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use uft and they seem to hide a lot of their documentation, but per http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Und_Chkpt_Statements.htm it looks like you should just pass a `Checkpoint` to the `Check` without the `= true`. Otherwise you're actually passing a boolean comparison to `Check` rather than the actual result of a `Checkpoint` call (whatever it returns).

I believe the Results Viewer is showing the results of the `Checkpoint` calls themselves, not the actual result of the `Check` function.